# How to share models across different services/repos using postgres/knex.js/objection.js in node.js?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

In standard micro-service architecture, each service is responsible for their own data with boundaries set. The only way to manipulate this data is through RESTful endpoints provided by the service.

I have a unique case where I would like to have a few clustered scraper processes running, populating a table with raw data. These scraper processes can also be configured for specific cases, say one to scrape text, one to scrape images, etc.

The raw data will then be consumed and aggregated into a normalized structure in another table by another process. I'd like to split out all this processes into small, deployable components, but that means that I must somehow share the model definitions across multiple repositories/projects since the aggregation logic must consume all the raw data.

It's possible that the aggregation logic makes request to each clustered scraper process, but the state control for that would be a lot more complex than just querying a table.

I know it's possible to define the model definitions in an isolated repo and then import as a dependency in other projects, but is this the correct architecture?

Answer (score 1):

The best case for when to use microservices is when you have very distinct bounded contexts in your problem domain. When you have overlapping context boundaries like the scenario you've described, microservices will probably cost you more than you'd gain. Do you feel like you'd gain productivity by deconstructing your application into microservices despite this issue?
Without a better look at your application, it's hard to give definitive answers, but when you're bumping into problems like this at the outset, there's a good chance that this isn't a good case for a microservice architecture. Bear in mind, that's just my two cents.
Sharing physical repositories for configuration sounds pretty onerous, and I'd avoid it if at all possible!

Comment: I believe I'll get more productivity due to sharing configuration or models but it will be hard on the deployment stage. I'm writing an AI service which will be the main entry point for users, but I'll be building out specialized scraper processes that will target a specific source to get training data, in this case multiple forums or maybe blog sites.

Comment: Thought about it for the night and I think the easiest way to handle this is for each process to make POST requests over to the training service. There will still be shared models but I guess the training service and entry service have more overlap in context than the others.